# Some style/theme attributes are not available in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently started to learn Android development. But when I click themes, to change it, it says:

> Rendering problems. Missing styles....

Then I can't push any Layout or view into the app.

I tried clicking **Auto add all the missing attributes**, but it doesn't do anything.

One of them works though - only the Manifest Theme.

These screenshot might help:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AO27.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XO3G.png)

Answer (score 1):

See in the image click on `Overscan` then the `dialog` is propmt change the Theme to `Holo light` the error will disappear.

Image :

[image]